# PreferenceFragment / PreferenceActivity crashes - cant figure out why

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferenceactivity

I want to implement a preference screen. So I followed basically the example from the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#addPreferencesFromResource%28int%29).
When I start the Activity I see the header list, with one header (this part seems to work). But as soon I click this header the Activity crashed with below log.

I searched SO and google, but couldn't find any further information on this error.

I tried to shorten **preference_appearance_screen.xml** to one CheckBoxPreference item. Still same error on XML Line 18. So I guess that the error is not to be found in this file.

**My activity class:**

```
public class TrainerPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
    }

    public static class AppearancePrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_appearance_screen);
        }
    }
}
```

**preference_headers.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preference-headers
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header android:fragment=".TrainerPreferenceActivity$AppearancePrefFragment"
           android:title="Appearance"
           android:summary="An example of some preferences." />
</preference-headers>
```

**preference_appearance_screen.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/pref_app_cat_theme">
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/pref_app_cat_background">
        <CheckBoxPreference 
            android:key="@string/pref_app_bg_iscustom_key" 
            android:title="@string/pref_app_bg_iscustom_title"
            android:summary="An example of some preferences."/>
        <CheckBoxPreference 
            android:key="@string/pref_app_bg_hascolor_key" 
            android:title="@string/pref_app_bg_hascolor_title"
            android:summary="An example of some preferences."/>  
        <CheckBoxPreference 
            android:key="@string/pref_app_bg_hasimage_key" 
            android:title="@string/pref_app_bg_hasimage_title"
            android:summary="An example of some preferences."/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/pref_app_cat_behavior">
        <CheckBoxPreference 
            android:key="@string/pref_app_orientationisenabled_key" 
            android:title="@string/pref_app_orientationisenabled_title"
            android:summary="An example of some preferences."/>        
        <CheckBoxPreference 
            android:key="@string/pref_app_gestureisenabled_key" 
            android:title="@string/pref_app_gestureisenabled_title"
            android:summary="An example of some preferences."/>
   </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**LogCat:**

> 04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #18: You must supply
>   a layout_width attribute. 04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):
>     at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5318)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:5271) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams.(AbsListView.java:5718)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.generateLayoutParams(AbsListView.java:5355)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.generateLayoutParams(AbsListView.java:86)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:477) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.preference.Preference.onCreateView(Preference.java:474) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:451) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:221)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723) 04-30 17:22:01.215:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723) 04-30 17:22:01.215:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723) 04-30 17:22:01.215:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723) 04-30 17:22:01.215:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:999)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:555) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723) 04-30 17:22:01.215:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723) 04-30 17:22:01.215:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723) 04-30 17:22:01.215:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723) 04-30 17:22:01.215:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723) 04-30 17:22:01.215:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 04-30 17:22:01.215:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-30 17:22:01.215:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   04-30 17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 04-30
>   17:22:01.215: E/AndroidRuntime(16775):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Have you tried a 'clean' on your project - just in case? Also, try using the fully qualified package name for the `android:fragment` reference. I don't see any obvious mistakes at a quick glance.

Comment: Fully qualified Name: i tried already. In case the name is misspelled (which I tried too) I get a class not found error thrown. After your comment I cleaned the project: no change.

Comment: Alright, I set up a quick test project, but I haven't been able to reproduce the error - it displays and works fine on my Galaxy Nexus. What device are you running this on, and have you tried any others/emulators? The only possibly related issue I could find is [this style/theming-related one](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg64082.html), which seems to pop up every here and there. Have you made any customizations? If so, try running above code as 'vanilla' as possible to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: That actually was the case. I have styled the listSeperatorTextView style. But it didnt came to me that this could be a problem here. Thank you so much for this hint. Post it as an answere and I will accept it.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad that's sorted out then. Happy coding - I copy-pasted my earlier comment as answer below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I set up a quick test project, but I haven't been able to reproduce the error - it displays and works fine on my Galaxy Nexus. What device are you running this on, and have you tried any others/emulators?

The only possibly related issue I could find is [this style/theming-related one](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg64082.html), which seems to pop up every here and there. Have you made any customizations? If so, try running above code as 'vanilla' as possible to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, that was quite a tough bug. I commented out this attribute in my file `styles.xml`: `<item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/MyListSeparator</item>` and the problem disappeared...

Answer (score 2):

This is because you referenced a custom style for your app which is being used by the preference screen, and that custom style is not inheriting those required properties. To preserve both your custom style AND avoid this issue, make sure your custom style has the "layout_width" and "layout_height" properties. In your case:

```
    <style name="MyListSeperator" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        ...
    </style>
```

and then you go ahead an uncomment:

```
    <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/MyListSeparator</item>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thank you very much!